# Use Taylor series to calculate C(a,2a)/ C(a,a) accurate to 0.001

Tags: taylor-expansion, elliptic-integrals

[image]

I have done 1 and 2. I think C(a,a) is a circle. I want to do No 4. I have got a answer to no 3 for E. But I havent idea to do no 4. I have got a answer to C(a,2a)/ C(a,a) from E. After that what how to do it??

Comment: What is what does C(a,b) mean

Comment: I think It is a circle @James

Comment: Maybe of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132196 and http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mcasquilho/compute/com/,ellips/PerimeterOfEllipse.pdf